Adding comment to a commit when Azure release pipeline fails
I have an Azure release pipeline that triggers a Salesforce Sandbox deployment when a developer pushes a commit to a dev branch(connected to the pipeline). Sometimes, this deployment fails, which also causes the release pipeline to fail. Currently, the developers do not receive a notification when this happens.
Is there a way to push a comment to the commit to notify the developer when their commits are causing issues on the dev sandbox?

If you know which commit you would wish to comment on, then it might be easier to simply send an email to the email address associated with that commit, compared to automating writing a comment in AzDO. Also, another way to handle this is with PRs and a gated check-in before it can be completed. If the pipeline fails the bad commit(s) won't even be merged into dev in the first place.

You can add a new job in your release pipeline to add comments to the commit using GitHub REST API Create a commit comment when the deployment job is failed.
Steps:

Add a new agent job after your deployment job.


Agent Specification: Agent Specification
Run this job: Only when a previous job has failed


Add a Command line task to run Github REST API to add comments to your commit.


SourceAlias: The alias of your github artifact.

GitHubOwner: The account owner of the repository.
GitHubRepoName: The name of the repository.
GitHub.Token: The GitHub PAT. Create it in GitHub with repo scope and store it in Azure DevOps pipeline as a secret variable.



The scripts:
COMMIT_ID=$(Release.Artifacts.{SourceAlias}.SourceVersion) 
echo $COMMIT_ID
curl -L \
    -X POST \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/{GitHubOwner}/{GitHubRepoName}/commits/$COMMIT_ID/comments" \
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: token $(GitHub.Token)" \
    -d '{"body":"The deployment is failed."}'

Result:
When the deployment is successful, the "Check Deploy" job will be skipped. When the deployment is failed, the "Check Deploy" job will add a comment to the commit that triggered the Azure release pipeline.


